# A war boy I am, yet

Tags: riddle

Last night I spent too much time watching some military weapon's video footage on YouTube.

As I fell asleep, a weapon's silhouette showed up in my dream, with a voice came from nowhere, read a poem sound like this:

> A birthmark I have, like a letter in capital.
>   
>   A war boy I am, yet friends regard me as a girl.
>   
>   Interested in music, though I'm playing it poorly. 
>   
>   On an iron stave with all the notes, a symphony has made proudly.
>   
>   When the concert begun, the notes were flying away.
>   
>   As the dull sound went on, the evil had faded away.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be the infamous

> [Katyusha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katyusha_rocket_launcher)

A birthmark I have, like a letter in capital.

> They were branded with the letter K

A war boy I am, yet friends regard me as a girl.

> It's a weapon of war nicknamed using a female name (Yekaterina →Katya →Katyusha)

Interested in music, though I'm playing it poorly.

> When fired it would produce an awful type of "music"

On an iron stave with all the notes, a symphony has made proudly.

> The "notes" are the individual rockets while the iron stave is the rack which holds them

When the concert begun, the notes were flying away.

> When it starts firing the rockets fly out in quick succession

As the dull sound went on, the evil had faded away.

**Explanation from OP:**

> Though the poor accuracy it had, but katyusha's rockets were effective in [carpet bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_bombing), along with the howling sound, which was feared by the German soldiers.

Comment: Right you are! The last explanation can be found in the reference you have.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> Mikhail Gorbachev

Reasoning:

Birthmark

> The birthmark on his forehead, looks vaguely like a T

Interested in music

> Released at least 1 album

Notes were flying away

> Proceeds of music activities went to charity

Evil had faded away

> End of the USSR and Cold War

Comment: No, it is a thing, not a person. Though they share the same nationality.

Comment: Is it something that requires specific knowledge or more general?

Comment: Well, it is a weapon, to be specific.